# Crash on run ios 9 notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

Getting error while running application:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotificationsUI.framework/UserNotificationsUI
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/021019C3-2654-4F9A-9E06-3C86B5EA6B04/iSRK-Diamonds.app/iSRK-Diamonds
  Reason: image not found
```

For notification in ios 10

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 19):

I would recommend checking the `UserNotificationsUI` framework is marked as Optional and not Required in your project settings.

You can do this by

- Opening on your `Xcode` Project in the project navigator.
- Select your `target` and navigate to the `Build Phases` tab.
- Expand the `Link Binary With Libraries` section.
- Make sure the status of the `UserNotificationsUI` framework is set to Optional.

This will ensure the framework is not forcefully loaded into memory, causing a crash on older versions of iOS.